# How to do on-the-spot MatLab debugging?

Tags: matlab

main.m goes

```
a
b
```

b.m goes

```
Line 1 to 489   (Many time-consuming codes are here)
Line 490        wi=function_example(fff,w0,factor,10);
```

But I got an error at line 490 of b.m

In this case, I want to retry

```
wi=function_example(fff,w0,factor,30);
```

right at the command window.

If I change the code itself and rerun the whole codes, it will take too much time (hours or even days) even to reach to the 490th line.

But since fff, w0, and factor were defined in b.m, fff, w0, and factor are not global variables.

So if I just type

```
 wi=function_example(fff,w0,factor,30);
```

then MatLab will say

```
Undefined function or variable 'fff'.
```

So I am curious about how to run just one intermediate line at command window, rather than changing the code itself and running the whole code again which takes too much time.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Is it related to the data itself, in other words, can it be reproduced by some smaller case? (i.e. if you have a grid, reduce its size by a factor 10^n).

Answer (score 4):

First you want to have MATLAB automatically start debugging when there is an error. You can easily do this by typing the following *before* running your script.

```
dbstop if error
```

Once an error occurs, MATLAB will automatically start [debugging](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) at the line where the error occurred and you will have access to all variables as needed.

Here is some more [information](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/examine-values.html) about how to examine the variables during debugging.

Comment: Thank you! But the document you linked says "From the Editor tab, in the Debug section, choose a workspace from the Function Call Stack menu list." but I can't see it. I am using MatLab 2015. Is this a new feature for MatLab 2016?

Comment: The Workspace selection menu is only visible once you have stopped in the debugger. (It's not a new feature.  It's been around for many many releases.)  Note also, that if you have stopped in the debugger because of using `dbstop if error` then you'll already be viewing the correct workspace, so you won't need to change the selection (unless you want to then look at other workspaces too).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to save the workspace right before that line and test it afterwards:

```
Line 1 to 489   (Many time-consuming codes are here)
Line 490        save
Line 491        wi=function_example(fff,w0,factor,10);
```

Afterwards, in command-line you just need to run:

```
load
wi=function_example(fff,w0,factor,10);
```

Comment: This is what I would. You don't risk to accidentally loose the work you have been doing by exiting the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

That is most probably not possible..since the variables like `fff`,`w0` etc. are declared and defined only when you run the script. What you can do is to call the function with appropriate values and see if the function is returning the correct value. For example say `function_example(1,2,3,30)` should return 40. See if the function returns the correct value. Bottom line - Test the function with known input values and see if it returns the correct result.

Comment: Thank you. But I can imagine, if this is possible, this will be immensely useful. Your solution will be possible if I print values out. But that will make the code slower and messier. Another solution is to "roll back" the execution of the code to some earlier point. Is this possible in MatLab?